登録されているデータにより紐づいているテーブルが変わる物のデータの取得方法が分からない。
分かりにくかったら申し訳ございません。
下記のテーブルで、hobby_skillsテーブルやhobbiesテーブルのtypeの値が1か3の場合、skill_idはteamsテーブルのidと紐づき、typeの値が2か4の場合、skill_idはusersテーブルのidと紐づいています。
hobby_skillsテーブルのhobby_idがhobbiesテーブルのidと紐づいています。
ここで、usersテーブルのデータをSELECT文で表示していく時に、それぞれ対応したtypeの値のtitleを同時に表示させたいです。
例えば、nakata, 30, キャッチャー, 正確……という感じで。
説明が難しいのですが、よろしくお願いいたします。
他サイトでも同時に質問させていただいております。
https://teratail.com/questions/ct0w4n56hcirce#reply-cxc64i34k6ss9l
テーブル情報
（※ここに登場するデータは仮情報なので本当のデータではありません）
teamsテーブル



id
title
……




1
巨人



2
阪神




usersテーブル



id
name
age
title
……




1
tanaka
25
ピッチャー



2
nakata
30
キャッチャー




hobbby_skillsテーブル



id
type
skill_id
hobby_id
……




1
1
1
1



2
2
2
2



3
3
3
3



4
4
4
4




hobbiesテーブル



id
type
title
……




1
1
早い



2
2
正確



3
3
丁寧



4
4
ピンチヒッター





他のサイトでも同じ内容の投稿 をされているようですが、予め質問の本文にその旨を明示しておいてもらうとスムーズに回答が付きやすくなると思います。 / 参考: マルチポストとはなんですか？何か問題があるのでしょうか？

追記致しました。

質問の 「対応したtypeの値のtitleを同時に表示させたいです。」ということに対して
例えば下記のようなSQLが参考になりますでしょうか？
※ GROUP_CONCATで順序を指定するようにしました。
※ ORDER BYを表示する文字列に変更しました。
SELECT CASE
         WHEN t.type IN (1, 3)
           THEN 'teams'
         WHEN t.type IN (2, 4)
           THEN 'users'
       END AS data,
       CASE
         WHEN t.type IN (1, 3)
           THEN teams.title
         WHEN t.type IN (2, 4)
           THEN users.title
       END AS title,
       #GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies.title) AS facilities
       GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies.title order by hobbies.title) AS facilities
  FROM hobbby_skills AS t
  LEFT OUTER JOIN teams
    ON teams.id = t.skill_id
   AND t.type IN (1, 3)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users
    ON users.id = t.skill_id
   AND t.type IN (2, 4)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbies
    ON hobbies.id = t.hobby_id
  GROUP BY t.type,
           teams.title,
           users.title,
           t.skill_id
  #ORDER BY t.type,
  #         teams.title,
  #         users.title,
  #         t.skill_id;
  ORDER BY data,
           title,
           t.skill_id;


テーブルの構成がいま一つ良くわかりませんが、
下記のようにすれば抽出できます。
なお、hobbby_skills に hs の別名を付けず hobbby_skills のまま使用しても構いません
SELECT users.name,
       users.age,
       users.title,
       hobbies.title
  FROM hobbby_skills AS hs
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users
    ON users.id = hs.skill_id
   AND hs.type IN (2, 4)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbies
    ON hobbies.id = hs.hobby_id
  WHERE hs.type IN (2, 4)
    AND users.id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY users.name,
           users.id,
           hobbies.title;

また、下記のようにしても同じ結果になります。
SELECT users.name,
       users.age,
       users.title,
       hobbies.title
  FROM (
        SELECT *
          FROM hobbby_skills
         WHERE type IN (2, 4)
       ) AS hs
  #INNER JOIN users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN users
    ON users.id = hs.skill_id
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbies
    ON hobbies.id = hs.hobby_id
  WHERE users.id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY users.name,
           users.id,
           hobbies.title;

なお、usersテーブルの LEFT OUTER JOIN を
INNER JOIN に変更すれば
WHERE users.id IS NOT NULL は必要ありません。
ご参考になれば、幸いです
追記）
hobbby_skills テーブルの skill_id に索引があれば、下記のようにした方が良いです。
SELECT users.name,
       users.age,
       users.title,
       hobbies.title
  FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbby_skills
    ON hobbby_skills.skill_id = users.id
   AND hobbby_skills.type IN (2, 4)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbies
    ON hobbies.id = hobbby_skills.hobby_id
  ORDER BY users.name,
           users.id,
           hobbies.title;

追記２）
質問から hobbby_skills の type と hobbies の type は同じになっていると思っています。
hobbby_skills の type が teams テーブルを指し、hobbies の type が users テーブルを指す場合、hobbby_skills の skill_id が何を指すかわからなくなるからです。
追記３）
質問にある他サイトの内容を確認すると下記のようなことをやりたいようですね？
SELECT users.name,
       users.age,
       users.title,
       GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies.title) AS facilities
  FROM users
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbby_skills
    ON hobbby_skills.skill_id = users.id
   AND hobbby_skills.type IN (2, 4)
  LEFT OUTER JOIN hobbies
    ON hobbies.id = hobbby_skills.hobby_id
  GROUP BY users.id
  ORDER BY users.name,
           users.id;

GROUP BY を使用しています。
不明点があれば、お知らせください。
追記４）
質問にある他サイトの内容の回答のSQLは下記と同等のようです。
SELECT users.name,
       users.age,
       users.title,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(hobbies.title)
          FROM hobbby_skills
          INNER JOIN hobbies
             ON hobbies.id = hobbby_skills.hobby_id
         WHERE hobbby_skills.skill_id = users.id
           AND hobbby_skills.type IN (2, 4)
       ) AS facilities
  FROM users
  ORDER BY users.name,
           users.id;

